QGIS "Create Vector Grid" code
I need to create code in a plugin to create parallel lines at a given heading and spacing within a polygon. This is very similar to what the "create vector grid" function does. It's found under the "Vector|Research" menu. I would rather modify that code than start from scratch, but I'm not sure where to even look for it. I imagine that like much functionality it was a plugin once.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

A quick search for createGrid in the QGis source code gives us the qgsalgorithmgrid.cpp class
